# How to validate HTML code using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, iframe

I want to dynamically render html code into iFrame in using JavaScript.

Before hand I want to validate if my html code is syntactically correct.

Is there any inbuilt method to achieve this.

Comment: I'd rather use one of the common frameworks to create the html instead of validating "handmade" html - unless you need to validate user provided html code.

Comment: Filburt this seems a great choice... but I am providing privilege to user to write html content which will be displayed in iFrame after validating it completely

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function like this:

```
function validateHTML(html) {
  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.innerHTML = html;
  return (elem.innerHTML===html);
}
```

But it depends on the browser, so it won't give 100% results. It's better to instead of validate, try to make it correct:

```
function correctHTML(html) {
  var elem = document.createElement('div');
  elem.innerHTML = html;
  return elem.innerHTML;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: This function works  fine for the opening and closing of tags..but can not check for the opening and closing of single or double quotes.

Comment: The [*DOM Parsing and Serialization specification*](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/innerhtml/raw-file/tip/index.html) does not require that the result of serialisation is identical to the input markup, only that the DOM created from both is the same. So doing a string compare between the two is bound to fail for non–trivial markup given that a difference of a single character will return false. E.g. `<table><tr><td></table>` is valid markup, but will probably (not certainly) be serialised with closing tags for the TR and TD. The serialisation may also include TBODY tags.

Comment: Is there any method to check for valid html code then

Answer (score 0):

There is the W3C Markup Validator Web Service which has a [*SOAP 1.2 interface*](http://validator.w3.org/docs/api.html).

Comment: unable to open this link

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for answering my own question

The perfect solution is

http://ejohn.org/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/

Easy implementation and clear solution